# iOS - Generate URL from UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, url

Is it possible to generate a local URL from a given UIImage?

Here is what I want to do :

1. Given a URL, I create an UIImage and store in variable (let's call it `myImage`)
2. Then I add a text to `myImage`

Is it possible to generate a URL from `myImage`? I am thinking about getting a URL from device local storage.

Comment: Where is the image saved?

Comment: the image is stored in a variable.

Comment: I mean on disk, urls are to a server or a file on disk generally

Comment: my UIImage myImage is created from an URL(Image stored in AWS)

Comment: Create a custom object with the properties you need: image, url, text, etc.

Comment: You can't get a URL from a UIImage that's just a collection of pixels in the RAM. You must save it somewhere first.

Comment: The thing is that I need to generate an URL because I am using an external library that requires URL to build UIViews

Comment: So tell us about this library, are the urls used for view navigation or identification? What is the library name? How are you creating other urls in the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the image programmatically in RAM you must save it somewhere on disk before you can generate a local URL from it.

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,      .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let urlPath= documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("filename.jpg")
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0).writeToFile(destinationPath, atomically: true)
let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
```

You can later delete it when it's not needed anymore.